# ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model

```
public function login($email,$password)
{
    $query = $this->db->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])
                        ->get('registration');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row();
    }
}
```

i am new in programming. There is syntax error . i couldn't understand the problem's solution

Comment: pls help me . I am in need.

Comment: ```$this->db->where('email', $email)->where('password',$password)
                        ->get('registration');``` check this

Comment: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object after assign a $query object

Comment: just use ```return $query->result()``` if you have to do nothing with count.

Comment: _“There is syntax error”_ - likely because you are using a _way_ outdated PHP version, that did not know the `[...]` syntax to create arrays yet. In that case, the first thing you should do is update your PHP version.

Comment: Check what is PHP version there. Square brackets can be used since `5.4+`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function login($email, $password)
{

   $array = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password);

   $this->db->where($array);
   $query = $this->db->get('registration');

   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $query->row();
      // return true;
   }

   return false;

}
```

Read through the manual codeigniter database library has lots of features.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Associative array method:

```
$array = array('name' => $name, 'title' => $title, 'status' => $status);
$this->db->where($array)
```